# Can I launch "window/icon" manager in specific directory in xfce

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, file-manager, file-management

I use xfce an I am organizing my playlist folder and I would like to have some nice interface to do it. I was thinking about some 2D file manager or launching "window/icon" manager in some specific directory but after some googling I've got desperate so here I am... Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

The default file manager for Xfce is Thunar. As stated on Thunar's manual page, "Thunar takes a list of URIs for folders that should be opened in new file manager windows" (see `man thunar`). Assuming you're account's home directory is called "Eddous" and includes a directory called "Playlist", `thunar /home/Eddous/Playlist` would open the Playlist directory in Thunar.

Comment: But thunar does not have good interface to organize things in directory

Comment: Your question specifies only that you're looking for 'some 2D file manager or launching "window/icon" manager'. Please consider editing your question to describe the type of interface that you're looking for.